# Is Communicating Sequential Processes [CSP] an alternative to the actor model in Scala?

Tags: scala, core.async, actor-model

In a [1978 Paper by Hoare we have an idea called Communicating Sequential Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes). This is used by [Go](http://godoc.org/github.com/thomas11/csp), [Occam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam_%28programming_language%29), and in Clojure in [core.async](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/clojure-core-async).

**Is it possible to use CSP as an alternative to the Actor Model in Scala?** (I'm seeing [JCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP#Using_JCSP_from_Other_Languages) but I'm wondering if this is the only option, if it is mature, and if anyone uses it).

EDIT - I'm also seeing [Communicating Scala Objects](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/bernard.sufrin/CSO/cpa2008-cso.pdf) as an alternative to JCSP in Scala. But those of these seem to be tied to real threads - which seems to miss one of the benefits of CSP, being to get away from the memory resource cost of keeping large numbers of threads always active.

Comment: a brief description for future - https://medium.com/@ssumit/concurrency-models-that-most-developers-should-know-44c0ed707413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consult [this document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Comparison_with_the_Actor_Model), but in general there are a few differences:

- Channels are anonymous while actors have identities
- In CSP, you use channels to transmit messages, but actors can directly contact each other.
- In CSP communication is done in the form of rendezvous (i.e., it is synchronous). Actors support asynchronous message passing.

*And yes, it is possible to use CSP as an alternative to the Actor model if these differences are acceptable in your position.* I don't have any experience with JCSP but I wouldn't recommend using that specific library (the reason is as I see there aren't any activity in the project since 2011).

Comment: In CSP, Channels are not anonymous. CSP is a process algebra so processes can be represented by a variable or an expression. Implementations of CSP may have anonymous processes.